# What is the difference between atomic mass and mass number?

Tags: mass, nuclear-physics, definition, binding-energy

As total number of nucleons in nucleus is equal to [mass number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_number). And is also called atomic mass number. I want to know that is there any difference between the two? Because in nuclear reactions mass number differs from atomic mass and the difference between two provides binding energy.

Answer (score 3):

The **mass number** is the number of nucleons (protons and neutrons) in the nucleus of an atom.
For example $^{12}_{\,\,6}\rm C$ has a mass number of $12$ as it has $6$ protons and $6$ neutrons in its nucleus and $^{35}_{17}\rm Cl$ has a mass number of $35$ as it has $17$ protons and $18$ neutrons in its nucleus.

---

The **atomic mass** of an atom is the mass of the atom in atomic mass units (amu or u).
The atomic mass of a  $^{12}_{\,\,6}\rm C$ atom is defined as being $12 $ atomic mass units.
The atomic mass of a $^{35}_{17}\rm Cl$ atom is $34.96885268$ atomic mass units ie a $^{35}_{17}\rm Cl$ atom is $\dfrac{34.96885268}{12}$ heavier than a $^{12}_{\,\,6}\rm C$ atom.

Note that the atomic mass is approximately equal to the mass number.

---

There is a third quantity which you should be aware of which is used by Chemists and that is the (standard) **atomic weight**.
The unit is again the atomic mass unit but it is the average atomic mass of the different types of atoms (isotppes) of which an element is composed.
For example in nature carbon exists as the isotopes $^{12}_{\,\,6}\rm C, \, ^{13}_{\,\,6}\rm C$ and $^{14}_{\,\,6}\rm C$ and so you will see the atomic weight of carbon listed as $12.011$ to reflect the fact that natural carbon is $75\%\,^{12}_{\,\,6}\rm C,\, 24\%\,^{13}_{\,\,6}\rm C$ with a trace of $^{14}_{\,\,6}\rm C$.
However the isotopic composition of Carbon may vary and so you will also see the standard atomic weight listed as a range of values such as $[12.0096 \,\,\,12.0116]$ when greater accuracy is required.

Comment: Do you mean to say that atomic mass and mass number has no difference?But ,in nuclear reactions, why there is a difference between the two?

Comment: RabikJohn They are different but I also wrote “Note that the atomic mass is **approximately** equal to the mass number. Mass number must be an integer whereas atomic mass is not.

Comment: Ok ,you mean they are not equal only"approximately" equal and the rest of their mass is converted into binding energy of nucleus.One more thing;Does atomic mass includes mass of electrons?

Comment: @RabikJohn Atomic mass is the mass of a stationary neutral atom.

Comment: You mean, yes ;it includes electron.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for pointing out my error which I hope I have now corrected?

Comment: @RabikJohn Yes, it includes electrons.

Comment: i think this should be asked in chemistry SE